# Expo dev - have a build error "Firebase project not found or not correctly mentioned on config.json"

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, mobile, expo

please help me to understand the problem. I recently made a build with expo dev, everything went well. But after some time, I needed to make another build and I got the following error:

`✔ Preparing the list of your Firebase projects Firebase project not found or not correctly mentioned on config.json error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command. yarn install exited with non-zero code: 1`

Mobile app build, react, expo dev

I tried rolling back to a backup to remove all changes, didn't help. Also, on the local device I wrote yarn install, yarn - no errors. The old build works with firebase normally, but exactly the same code is not buildable now. Also, I checked all settings and config - everything is normal. I do not understand what the problem is. Please help.
And the command `firebase projects:list` give projets list succesfully in my local environment (vsc)

Thanks